# Magento 2: Apply shipping rate to quote

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, quote, table-rates, shipping-rates

I want to apply the matrix rate shipping method which has multiple rates based on quantity in the cart. I tried the following code but it is not working

```
$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()->setShippingMethod('matrixrate');
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
OR
$quote->setShippingAmount(666);
$quote->getTotals->setShippingAmount(666);
$quote->save();
```

I cannot see any rates added in the `quote_shipping_rate` table in the database.

```
$shippingAddress->getAllShippingRates() is also returning empty values
```

How to apply the shipping rate to the quote?

Comment: Please share solution for this